# How do I remap a key to a key-combination in the Windows 7 registry?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry, remapping

I have been able to remap the CapsLock key (3A) to the Left Shift key (2A) by adding the binary value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map` to the registry with a value of:

```
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00

02 00 00 00  2A 00 3A 00

00 00 00 00
```

How can I modify this value so that the key remaps to a multiple-key combination, for example Alt-Shift?

Comment: I thought Keyboard Layout could only be used to map one key to another one. Is there any restriction from using third party apps? AutoIt or AutoHotKey would be perfect for this

Comment: Thanks. I can definitely do this with AutoHotKey, however I was hoping that I could do it in the registry so that I wouldn't have another process running. If this can't be done in the registry, then I guess that's my answer.

Comment: AutoHotKey is my third party app of choice for this sort of thing.

Comment: sorry for reviving this old question, but I want to do a similar thing. 
I want to bind AltGr + esdf to the arrow keys.
In the windows keyboard layout creator these kind of key combinations can be bound, but only to characters it seems.
I was wondering if the scancode could be remapped in the registry, as a workaround.
i don't want to install Autohotkey on my company computer but i can install custom keyboard layout drivers and add registry entries, so it would be awesome if it would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two options shown here at  [AutoHotKey: Remapping via the Registry's "Scancode Map"](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#registry) , might be what you are looking for...

(1) Use a program like [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) (freeware) to visually remap your keys. It will change the registry for you.

(2) Remap keys manually by creating a .reg file (plain text) and loading it into the registry. This is demonstrated at www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-56216.html#56216

Comment: While neither of these solutions do exactly what I was looking for, the information you gave me has helped lead me to the conclusion that what I want to do is probably not possible with the registry. It appears that AutoHotKey or something similar is my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

To remap a multiple-key combination:

1. Install **Power Toys** ([Visit here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install))
2. Open it and go to *Keyboard Manager*
3. Use one of these options depending on your needs: *Remap a key* or *Remap a shortcut*
4. Set the remapping and click OK