# How can I remap the windows key + arrow key combination in windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, button-remapping

For example, I'm looking for a way to remap the key combination

<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>

to

<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

I'd appreciate any suggestions or things to try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remap a key to a key-combination in the Windows 7 registry?](http://superuser.com/questions/320705/how-do-i-remap-a-key-to-a-key-combination-in-the-windows-7-registry) We have *lots* of questions on Windows key remapping, and in almost all cases where SharpKeys or similar can't help you'll find that AutoHotkey is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f) in Microsoft Support it's impossible to remap the keys, you can only disable the hotkeys.

**Edit**: I've found [this application](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), I think it will do. Remember to run it as administrator!

Comment: Thanks but I can't remap a key *combination* to another key combination with this

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121760/remap-keyboard-combinations-not-just-single-registry-values)

Comment: first answer doesn't do key combinations with the windows key and second answer's tool costs money.