# AutoHotkey Capslock::Ctrl doesn't work in some applications

Tags: autohotkey, capslock

I have the snippet `Capslock::Ctrl` in my autohotkey script that runs at system startup and my CapsLock is correctly turned into a Ctrl key, except for a few applications.

If regedit or XYplorer are focused, then CapsLock key toggles the state of CapsLock.

I want my CapsLock to always **always** act like a Ctrl key. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: If it is consistant and not intermittant in certian application, do you figure those apps are using a method that AHK does not work for? What if you remapped the key in the system registry? Do you want this change to be fully system wide? To be mostly permenent ?  http://superuser.com/questions/320705/how-do-i-remap-a-key-to-a-key-combination-in-the-windows-7-registry?s=5|0.7897

Comment: The problem always occurs when I'm on those apps, not intermittently. I don't know a whole lot about windows, so am unaware of the methods used by AHK. I do want the change to apply system-wide. I'll try the options on the linked page. Thanks.